# Check JSON value in a string with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

In my Rails I have two models, both with a method giving JSON back. One model is rent.rb the other is buy.rb. I also have a map.js, which will show a map with different pins, depending on the model, basically. So one map shows pins with apartments to rent, another - with apartments to buy. So, now I need a tooltip with a different information, depending on buy / rent. So I defined this part (as it's not coming from database), for rent.rb:

```
information {
  ...
  type: "rent"
}
```

and for buy.rb with :

```
 information {
   ...
   type: "buy"
 }
```

So now, in my map.js I wish to find out type and depending on what I get show the right information

```
(type == "rent") ? (show information for rent) : (type == "buy") ? (show information for buy)
```

But somehow JS won't access this value and won't customize information shown. Unfortunatelly I can't show the code, as it's for work. But maybe I am just using the wrong syntax here ...

Comment: What do you mean by "But somehow JS won't access this value and won't customize information shown"? Do you get any erroros?

Comment: No, it just returns the "rent" information on both maps.

Comment: Is the problem in your ternary operator, you mean? @KatharinaSchreiber If yes, then yeah the syntax is invalid

Comment: Have you verified that the value of `type` is a string? I assume your show conditions are pseudocode and the real code are function calls.

Comment: I use JavaScript’s Template Strings, and inside I get data from the model, which gets data from Database. So it worked perfect with if (?) and else and else if statements.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot join conditional operators like way you showed. Also you cannot have a function between ? and :

It will be better to do something like this

```
var rentInformation="some value";
var buyInformation="some other value";
var displayInformation = (type == "rent") ? rentInformation : buyInformation;
somePopupFunction(displayInformation);
```

Comment: It's not clear whether the ternary operator is the problem or it's just a sudo code. *Also you cannot have a function between ? and :* why not?

Comment: Looks like the ternary operator is the culprit unless it is sudo code , also it is probably safer to use strict equality `===` instead of `==`